# Run multiple subprocess commands

Tags: python

I'm having trouble in getting Python [AVL](http://web.mit.edu/drela/Public/web/avl/).

I need to run a two commands in sequence and get the string of the entire result for further processing:

1. `wine /Applications/avl.exe ~/documents/aerodynamics_project/input_cases/somefile.avl`
   This brings up the command prompt of the problem.
2. `OPER` to run the case

Ideally, I'd then like to pipe the entire output to a string. I cannot figure out how to do this. Current code:

```
p = subprocess.Popen("wine /Applications/avl.exe ~/documents/aerodynamics_project/input_cases/1_0.2_-0.26.avl", shell = True)
time.sleep(3)
text = p.communicate("OPER")
print(text)
```

It runs the first command (showing the results in the terminal) and then does not do anything. Replacing communicate with call just returns `AttributeError: 'Popen' object has no attribute 'call'`, so it clearly runs that far.

Comment: what happens when you run the wine command from a terminal?

Comment: @riotburn it works although I cannot get it to run in a single line. First command is fine and boots up the command-line interface for the software, then I need to type `OPER` to run the case. The second command seems to screw up in Python...

Comment: did you try setting sleep to something longer?

Comment: @riotburn PyCharm prompt seems to suggest that the original command never finishes as it waits for input independently of python...

Comment: try running your script directly from the command line and not from pycharm, see if there is a difference.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try passing as explicit param? And also, use stdin as PIPE

```
p = subprocess.Popen("wine /Applications/avl.exe ~/documents/aerodynamics_project/input_cases/1_0.2_-0.26.avl", shell = True, stdin=subprocess.PIPE).stdin
time.sleep(3)
text = p.communicate(input="OPER")[0]
print(text.decode())
```

Comment: Throws an error :(

File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/username/Documents/aerodynamics_project/analyze_cases.py", line 28, in <module>
    text = p.communicate(input="OPER")[0]
AttributeError: '_io.BufferedWriter' object has no attribute 'communicate'

Comment: hit the enter key too quickly. now included :P